# Опечатка при переводе причины отклонения правки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вместо `автор` должно быть `автора`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, ошибка. 
Исправил в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262719).